How to convert a normal java class into spring managed class and create beans in spring boot
Hi folks i have an use case to convert the code to asyncronus code using spring boot.
@Service
public class TaggedPdfReaderToolone extends TaggedPdfReaderTool {
@Autowired
ViewTagUtils viewTagUtils;

protected int order;
/**
 * Constructs a {@link TaggedPdfReaderTool} via a given {@link PdfDocument}.
 *
 * @param document the document to read tag structure from
 */
public TaggedPdfReaderToolone(PdfDocument document) {
    super(document);
}

@Override
public TaggedPdfReaderToolone setRootTag(String rootTagName) {
    this.rootTag = rootTagName;
    order =0;
    return this;
}

@Override
@Async
public void convertToXml(OutputStream os)
        throws IOException {
    convertToXml(os, "UTF-8");
}

@Override
@Async
public void convertToXml(OutputStream os, String charset)
        throws IOException {
    out = new OutputStreamWriter(os, Charset.forName(charset));
    if (rootTag != null) {
        out.write("<" + rootTag + ">" + System.lineSeparator());
    }
    // get the StructTreeRoot from the document
    PdfStructTreeRoot structTreeRoot = document.getStructTreeRoot();
    if (structTreeRoot == null)
        throw new PdfException(KernelExceptionMessageConstant.DOCUMENT_DOES_NOT_CONTAIN_STRUCT_TREE_ROOT);
    // Inspect the child or children of the StructTreeRoot
    inspectKids(structTreeRoot.getKids());
    out.write("</page> ");
    if (rootTag != null) {
        out.write("</" + rootTag + ">");
    }
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}

}
i am using a method from the above class in other class
@Slf4j
@Service
public class Viewtag {

@Autowired
ViewTagUtils viewTagUtils;

public void gettagcontent(String taggedPdf, String xmlfilepath) throws IOException {
    log.info("Viewing tagged page content started "+ taggedPdf);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(taggedPdf);
//        log.info("Before file load.");
    //filePathBean.setFilePath(taggedPdf);
    PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(reader);
    log.info("After file load.");
    viewTagUtils.setPagNumber(0);


    if (doc.isTagged()) {
        log.info("view tagged content called");
        log.info(xmlfilepath);
        FileOutputStream xmlOut = new FileOutputStream(xmlfilepath);
   //            new TaggedPdfReaderTool(doc).setRootTag("root").convertToXml(xmlOut);
        TaggedPdfReaderToolone taggedPdfReaderToolone = new 
     TaggedPdfReaderToolone(doc);
        taggedPdfReaderToolone.setRootTag("root").convertToXml(xmlOut);
    }else
        log.info("PDF is not a tagged pdf.");
    doc.close();
    log.info("Viewing tagged page content completed "+ taggedPdf);
}
}

I got an error consider creating a bean PdfDocument
after encountering this error i have done the configuration
as shown below ,
@Configuration
public class BeanCreation {


@Bean
public PdfDocument createPdfDocument(String filePath) throws IOException {
    return new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(filePath));
}
}

After doing the configuration
Now i am getting the error
consider creating a bean java.lang.String in BeanCreation,
Note:- The project i am working is gradel build and no xml file usage is done .
Any inputs to solve the issue will be help full
Thanks.

Can you show the full stacktrace?

You are registering a single instance of the PdfDocument class. String filePath is its Bean dependency and consequently you would need to register it as well, which is most likely not what you want. I assume you need to create a pdf document for a dynamic file path.
Instead of registering a Bean of type PdfDocument, register a Bean of an intermediate service layer such as PdfGeneratorService which will expose an API that takes the desired path and delegate the generation to your PdfDocument.
